# IP Camera with opencv: error ffmpeg

Tags: opencv, ip-camera

i am using VIVOTEK IP camera. I am trying to interface it with OPENCV. internet explorer shows fine video at this url, after entering username and password.

the code is given below

```
const std::string videoStreamAddress ="http://192.168.100.128/main.html";

//i have also tried "http://username:pasword@192.168.100.128/main.html" but the same
//result 
//and also tried ""http://192.168.100.128" i.e without "main.html"

if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress))
{

    std::cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;


    }
```

I got the following error

```
 warning: Error openong file <../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:529>
 Error opening video stream or file
```

what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The URL which you have given is the problem. You can use url something like this

```
"http://username:password@ipOfCamera/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480&req_fps=30&.mjpg"
```

Or another option is to download iSpy software and use IP camera wizard where it finds the URL for you and gives the best choice for the camera you are using. I did use this approach.
[Heres the code which worked for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613453/warning-could-not-find-codec-parameters-modules-highgui-src-cap-ffmpeg-i) as far as you want to get the live feed from the IP Camera.
[Here's the list of URL which can be used to get the video from your IP Camera.](http://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=vivotek).