# warning: Could not find codec parameters (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:540)

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ip-camera

I am trying to display the video feed from IP camera getting the following error

```
warning: Could not find codec parameters 

(../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:540)
```

Here's the code for the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv; 
using namespace std;
int main(int, char**) 
{ 
VideoCapture vcap; 
Mat image;
// This works on a D-Link CDS-932L
const string videoStreamAddress = "http://admin:admin123@172.41.20.55:80/?    action=stream?dummy=param.mjpg";//From mjpeg streamer
//const string videoStreamAddress = "http://192.168.1.13:8080/videofeed?   dummy=param.mjpg"; // Streaming from android using ip-cam

//open the video stream and make sure it's opened
if(!vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)) {


cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << std::endl;
return -1;
}

for(;;) {
if(!vcap.read(image)) {
    cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
    waitKey();
}
cv::imshow("Output Window", image);
    if(cv::waitKey(1) >= 0) break;
}
}
```

First i got different error so I installed K-Lite codec. Now I am getting this error.
Can some one please tell me what is the error related to.
I have gone through many post from stackoverflow and opencv also but could manage to get a satisfactory answer.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What OpenCV version do you have installed?

Comment: @karlphillip: I have openCv 2.4.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to Solve the problem with the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(){

CvCapture *camera=cvCaptureFromFile("http://username:password@ipOfCamera/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480&req_fps=30&.mjpg");
if (camera==NULL)
    printf("camera is null\n");
else
    printf("camera is not null");

cvNamedWindow("img");
while (cvWaitKey(10)!=atoi("q")){
    double t1=(double)cvGetTickCount();
    IplImage *img=cvQueryFrame(camera);
    /*if(img){
        cvSaveImage("C:/opencv.jpg",img);
    }*/
    double t2=(double)cvGetTickCount();
    printf("time: %gms  fps: %.2g\n",(t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.), 1000./((t2-t1)/(cvGetTickFrequency()*1000.)));
    cvShowImage("img",img);
}
cvReleaseCapture(&camera);
}
```

Would be good if it helps someone like me.
Also Thanks @karlphillip for giving your time.

Comment: Click on the checkbox near your answer to select it as the official.

Answer (score 3):

**Warnings are not errors!** Relax.

In this case FFmpeg is complaining and not OpenCV. [The reason is probably because the **mjpg** format that is specified on the URL doesn't really require an actual codec.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3735933/176769)

Comment: I have just now installed ffmpeg successfully still I get the same warning.

Comment: As I said: warnings are not necessarily problems. This one might not even be fixable. Does your program displays the captured frame correctly?

Comment: I am able to capture frames using USB webcam. not with the IP Camera